# How to get an executable path on Linux

Tags: linux, path

I am calling an 'executable' on Linux. One way by console and another from a PHP script. They both call other executables (I see it by the version of the file). So I need a way to display a path to the executable that will be called when I try to run it. How do I do this on Linux?

Comment: It might be as this because the http server is running in a chrooted environnement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
$ which yourcommand
```

For example

```
$ which cat
   /bin/cat
```

You can also get the full path with

```
$ echo $PATH
   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11
```

The `:` separate the paths that are used, in order or preference.

Note that the PATH can be different between users, so if your PHP script is executed with the `www-data` user for example, you have to check the PATH set for `www-data`. In general, it might be safer to specify the full path to the executable when you need to use a specific version of a program.

Answer (score 4):

In Bash, use `type -a command`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
# which your_binary
```

or

```
# locate your_binary
```

to see where the binaries or located.